# Fix "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform

I struggle to have an AWS Lambda function to connect to an AWS ElasticSearch cluster.

I have an AWS Lambda function defined as the following:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "fun1" {
  function_name = "fun1"
  role = aws_iam_role.ia0.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = local.security_group_ids
    subnet_ids         = local.subnet_ids
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT = "https://${aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.endpoint}"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ia0" {
  name = "lambda-exec-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role = aws_iam_role.ia0.id
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" {
  role = aws_iam_role.ia0.id
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" {
  role = aws_iam_role.ia0.id
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.arn
}
```

My VPC is defined like that:

```
locals {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg0.id]
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.private_a.id, aws_subnet.private_b.id]
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc0" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc0.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc0.cidr_block, 2, 1)
  availability_zone = "eu-west-3a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc0.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc0.cidr_block, 2, 2)
  availability_zone = "eu-west-3b"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg0" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc0.id
}
```

Finally my cluster looks like that:

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name = "es"
  elasticsearch_version = "7.9"

  cluster_config {
    instance_count         = 2
    zone_awareness_enabled = true
    instance_type          = "t2.small.elasticsearch"
  }

  domain_endpoint_options {
    enforce_https = true
    tls_security_policy = "Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07"
  }

  ebs_options {
    ebs_enabled = true
    volume_size = 10
  }

  vpc_options {
    security_group_ids = local.security_group_ids
    subnet_ids         = local.subnet_ids
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "rp0" {
  name   = "rp0"
  role   = aws_iam_role.ia0.id
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.arn}",
        "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.es.arn}/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "${aws_subnet.private_a.cidr_block}",
            "${aws_subnet.private_b.cidr_block}"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Despite of that I still get this answer

```
Response
  { responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 403, statusMessage = "Forbidden"}
  , responseVersion = HTTP/1.1
  , responseHeaders =
        [("Date","xxx")
        ,("Content-Type","application/json")
        ,("Content-Length","72")
        ,("Connection","keep-alive")
        ,("x-amzn-RequestId","xxx")
        ,("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
        ]
  , responseBody = "{\"Message\":\"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPut\"}\"
  , responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose
  }"
```

According to [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/) using CIDR should be sufficient, but in practice, something is missing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you attaching that role policy to? And what access policies if any do you have attached to the ES domain?

Comment: Can you show full, reproducable definition of `aws_elasticsearch_domain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to sign the request before making a http call to tell Elastic search from who is initiating the request. I don't know which programming language you are using, here is what we can do in NodeJs

For simple http call

```
    let request = new (AWS as any).HttpRequest(endpoint, 'us-east-1');
    let credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
    let signers = new (AWS as any).Signers.V4(request, 'es');
    signers.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());
```

if you are using a package like @elastic/elasticsearch, you can combine http-aws-es to create a client which creates a signature , might look something like

```
let options = {
    hosts: [ yourHost ], 
    connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'), 
    awsConfig: new AWS.Config({ region: 'us-east-1', credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS') })
};
client = require('elasticsearch').Client(options);
```

Comment: That's not true if you set a public access policy and just restrict using security groups.

Comment: Agreed.But Error 'User: anonymous...'  typically means ES access policy is restricted to certain Principals and we need to sign the request.

Comment: Yes but that might not be what they want. Jumping in with this answer when they might want to just restrict by security group is a little premature so it's normally worth discussing it with the OP in comments first as they might not be aware of the options. It's a good start of an answer if they do want to use AWS sig v4 signing and IAM permissions though. Expanding it to talk about what IAM permissions the user/role will need would also help.

Comment: It was my issue (along with a poorly configured policy). I use bloodhound (in Haskell), I thought I could not signed my queries until I have founded https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bloodhound-amazonka-auth